# jq add additional variable prefix

Tags: json, key, jq, key-value

I recently asked a couple of jq paring questions, and with all of the perfect answers, I did learn a lot. I hope this question is still possible..

```
{
   "kind":"ServiceList",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "items":[
      {
         "spec":{
            "ports":[
               {
                  "name":"https",
                  "protocol":"TCP",
                  "port":443,
                  "targetPort":6443
               },
                              {
                  "name":"http",
                  "protocol":"TCP",
                  "port":80,
                  "targetPort":8080
               }
            ],
            "clusterIP":"10.233.0.1",
            "type":"ClusterIP",
            "sessionAffinity":"None"
         },
         "status":{
            "loadBalancer":{
               
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "spec":{
            "ports":[
               {
                  "protocol":"TCP",
                  "port":80,
                  "targetPort":80,
                  "nodePort":40001
               }
            ],
            "selector":{
               "run":"my-httpd"
            },
            "clusterIP":"10.233.27.102",
            "type":"NodePort",
            "sessionAffinity":"None",
            "externalTrafficPolicy":"Cluster"
         },
         "status":{
            "loadBalancer":{
               
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The desired output is:

```
port01name=https;port01protocol=TCP;port01port=443;port01targetPort=6443;port02name=http;port02protocol=TCP;port02port=80;port02targetPort=8080
port01protocol=TCP;port01port=80;port01targetPort=80;port01nodePort=40001
```

It basically concatenates multiple ports per item into 1 line and put extra port{n} as a prefix.

Is it still possible to be done in jq?

Alternatively, the output can be below, and I tried to manipulate it afterward.

```
portname=https;portprotocol=TCP;portport=443;porttargetPort=6443;portname=http;portprotocol=TCP;portport=80;porttargetPort=8080
portprotocol=TCP;portport=80;porttargetPort=80;portnodePort=400
```

Comment: Yes, both are possible; in fact, both are very easy.  But what is the specific problem you’re running into?  (SO is not a free programming service.) Also, some tightening of the requirements would be a good idea.

Comment: I am kind of jq newbie... The best I have is '.items[] .spec.ports[] | to_entries |  map("port01\(.key)=\(.value)") | join(";")'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your lead, let's start with:

```
.items[] .spec.ports[] | to_entries | map("port01\(.key)=\(.value)") | join(";")
```

This has two problems with respect to the first set of requirements:

a) it produces three separate strings;
b) "port01" is hardwired into the prefix.

The first issue can be resolved by wrapping the relevant subexpression in square brackets, and then using join(";") again.

To resolve the second issue, it helps to have a helper function for inserting leading zeros. The following would suffice:

```
def leadingZeros($n): tostring | "0"*($n - length) + .;
```

This can now be used to solve the problem according to the first set of requirements:

```
.items[].spec
| [.ports
   | range(0;length) as $ix
   | .[$ix]
   | to_entries
   | map("port\($ix+1|leadingZeros(2))\(.key)=\(.value)")
   | join(";") ]
| join(";")
```

### Global index

If the requirements were modified to require the port indices to be global, we could go with the following variant:

```
def addIndex(stream): foreach stream as $x (0; .+1; [., $x]);

addIndex(.items[].spec.ports[])
  | (.[0]|leadingZeros(2)) as $ix
  | .[1]
  | to_entries
  | map("port\($ix)\(.key)=\(.value)")
  | join(";")
```

With the -r command-line option, this produces one line per port:

```
port01name=https;port01protocol=TCP;port01port=443;port01targetPort=6443
port02name=http;port02protocol=TCP;port02port=80;port02targetPort=8080
port03protocol=TCP;port03port=80;port03targetPort=80;port03nodePort=40001
```

Comment: Wow, amazing. I can fully understand the first fix now. It might take me a while to digest the second fix.